# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'UserRole'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

this my code for create a dropdown list for login user then user select role and search in Tabel for check exist user .

Controller :

```
  var roles = _database.Tbl_Role.Select(r => new {RoleID = r.RoleID.ToString(), RoleName = r.RoleTitle}).ToList();
        ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(roles, "RoleID", "RoleName");
```

View Model :

```
 public class ViewModel
{
    public class ViewLogin
    {
        [Required]

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]

        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]

        public string UserRole { get; set; }

        [Required]

        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View :

```
       <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserRole)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserRole, ViewBag.Roles as SelectList, "-- نقش خود را مشخص کنید --", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control"})
            </div>
```

it show me this error :

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'UserRole'.

whats the problem ?

**Update**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(ViewModel.ViewLogin login)
    {
        if (login.UserRole=="1")
        {
            if (_users.CheckAdminExist(login.UserName,login.Password))
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "ورود با موفقیت انجام شد";
                ViewBag.Color = "Green";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "مدیری با چنین مشخصاتی یافت نشد";
                ViewBag.Color = "Red";
            }
        }
        else if (login.UserRole=="2")
        {
            if (_users.CheckStudentExist(login.UserName, login.Password))
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "ورود با موفقیت انجام شد";
                ViewBag.Color = "Green";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "دانش آموزی با چنین مشخصاتی یافت نشد";
                ViewBag.Color = "Red";
            }
        }
        else if (login.UserRole=="3")
        {
            if (_users.CheckTeacherExist(login.UserName, login.Password))
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "ورود با موفقیت انجام شد";
                ViewBag.Color = "Green";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "معلمی با چنین مشخصاتی یافت نشد";
                ViewBag.Color = "Red";
            }
        }
        return PartialView("_LoginPartial");
    }
}
```

Comment: It means that the value of `ViewBag.Roles` is `null` (probably because you submit a form and return the view but did not repopulate the `SelectList`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i update the question

Comment: The code you have shown has nothing to do with it. You need to shown the code in your POST method. And you need to confirm is this happens when you first display the page, or just when you submit the form.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Waht Shouls i do ?

Comment: i put all code in question

Comment: You have not repopulated `ViewBag.Roles` in the POST method before you return the view (refer the dupe). And why are you returning a PartialView?

Comment: Idont Know . . . . this for test